# my sql syntax error

Tags: mysql, dbforge

I exported a DB using dbForge (v6) and the whole script has a problem with this:

```
USE `global-cms-content2`;
CREATE TABLE `global-cms-content2`.umbracorelationtype (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DUAL bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PARENTOBJECTTYPE char(36) NOT NULL,
  CHILDOBJECTTYPE char(36) NOT NULL,
  NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ALIAS varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Error is :

```
1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DUAL bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PARENTOBJECTTYPE char(36) NOT NULL,
  CHILDOBJECTTYPE ' at line 3 SQL2.sql 2 1
```

Same error happens even when I create the table manually using the editor.

Why is MySQL not working with its own scripts?
Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

This did it!

```
USE `global-cms-content3`;
CREATE TABLE `global-cms-content3`.umbracorelationtype (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DUAL` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `PARENTOBJECTTYPE` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDOBJECTTYPE` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ALIAS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Still not sure why the export script or the backup DB script doesn't take care of reserved keywords... anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word DUAL is a keyword. See [Keyword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).
Try to quote the word as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `global-cms-content2`.umbracorelationtype (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DUAL` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PARENTOBJECTTYPE char(36) NOT NULL,
  CHILDOBJECTTYPE char(36) NOT NULL,
  NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ALIAS varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Comment: Yepp!! Got it to wrok